# How do i rotate a text/image every 2 seconds?

Tags: css

I have here a CSS code that can rotate any text/image **180%** on hover:

```
.card-container {
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Can I change that to rotate every 2 seconds? Rather than just waiting for someone to hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an infinite [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) rather than a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/owcywjfw/)

```
.card {
    animation: rotate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
```

Just add vendor prefixes for additional browser support. They were omitted here for brevity.